# Bootstrap modal is not opening on Google Maps marker click

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps, bootstrap-modal

I tried several options but did not succeed. My main goal is to open a Bootstrap modal.centered with info about the location. I tried to put trigger button it to infoWindow, but when I click on it page shows only grey semitransparent background. I made a simple map where I tried to test.

`My codepen: https://codepen.io/ilja-ankipovits/pen/QWWQyqK`

I added only the beginning of the modal and whole Google Map Script.
I am new with google API so additional explanations are welcomed.

Comment: From your Codepen, you have a ways to go before you are ready to do what you described above. Start simpler https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/adding-a-google-map

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is stuck with the sane issue, with love :):

```
div id="map"></div>
<script>
  var map;
  function initMap() {
    var artavenue = {lat:59.441970, lng: 24.784039};
    var artavenue2 = {lat:59.421521, lng: 24.724763};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
zoom: 4,
center: {lat:59.4370, lng:24.7536},
});

var markerA = new google.maps.Marker({
position: artavenue,
map: map,
title: 'Hello World!'
});
markerA.addListener('click', function(e) {
map.setCenter(this.position);
$('#art-avenue-modal').modal('show');
});

var markerB = new google.maps.Marker({
position: artavenue2,
map: map,
title: 'Hello World!2'
});
markerB.addListener('click', function(e) {
map.setCenter(this.position);
$('#art-avenue-modal2').modal('show');
});
}
</script>
```